# VS2013: Framework 4.5.1 is not installed?

Tags: c#, frameworks, vsto, outlook-addin

Using VS2013, I've updated my VSTO (Outlook AddIn) to fw 4.5.1, set prerequirements to 4.5.1 and published it.

All clients gets this error...

[image: Error]

And that is eventhough it's on a Windows 8.1 (which comes with 4.5.1) or it's Windows 7 clients with 4.5.1 installed.

Any idea why it's failling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VSTO was too old. Download and install latest version (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=140384).

Comment: That was unintuitive.  The VSTO version you linked is old too, sure it is correct?  What was the VSTO version you originally used?